# Running CKEditor in Fancy Box: Editor popups/overlays focus behind fancybox overlay

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fancybox-3

I am using fancy box to open various edit functions in an in line div.  I use ajax to get the div contents, move it into the div, and open the div in Fancybox. Mostly works great. Some edit blocks have the ckeditor in them and that loads fine and mostly works... but the ckeditor popup/overlays (like paste from word, the color selectors or image tools) are opening underneath the fancybox window. Maybe a z-index issue, but not sure how to fix it:

Fancy box code is below:

```
   function openEditBlock() {
      $.fancybox.open({
      src  : '#editBlock',
      type : 'inline',
      touch: false
    });
  }
```

CK Editor Code below:

```
    var editor1 = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1_content', 
    {
    extraPlugins: 'stylesheetparser', // load the plugin
    contentsCss: '../css/editor_cmsPages.css', // load custom stylesheet
    stylesSet: [], // Do not load the default Styles configuration.
    height: '480px',
    width: '780px',
    });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor1, 'wysfind/' ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

fancybox elements have z-index values from 99992 to 99995; but 1) ckeditor places dialog elements outside the content, as last children of `<body>` and 2) uses quite low starting values for z-index, for example, color selector has 10006 by default.

Luckily, ckeditor allows to configure z-indexes, locate config.js file and change value of `baseFloatZIndex` to smth like `100001` (see https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-baseFloatZIndex)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.